# How to create animated expanded menu

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I want to create the animated menu like in the attached image.

[image]

When hitting the round button (with the up arrow), it will expanded upwards (as in the 2nd image). Note: image drawn not to scale, pardon me for that.

[image]

My rough ideas will be like this:

- In the expanded menu, first row and second row are of the same view
  type, so I will create a layout file for that view
- The third row will
  be another layout.
- Use a container (FrameLayout) to host the round
  ImageButton (the one with  arrow)
- `onCreate` of the activity,
  inflate the container, add all the above views, but set visible only
  to the first row and the round    button.
- When the round button is
  toggled, just set visible/invisible other views.

My questions:

- Anything wrong with my approach, any pointer to a good tutorial?
- The container should be the FrameLayout or something else?
- In setting visible/invisible other views, how to create effect of really expanding and collapse?

Sorry if the questions are vague. Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Sliding Drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Inspire from [example here](http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2012/10/android-slidingdrawer-example.html)..

Here is complete code ..

```
public class SlidingDrawerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button slideButton,b1, b2,b3;
SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding_drawer);
slideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
b3.setOnClickListener(this);
slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened() {
slideButton.setText("V");
}
});
slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed() {
slideButton.setText("^");
}
});
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Button b = (Button)v;
Toast.makeText(SlidingDrawerActivity.this, b.getText() + " is Clicked :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**activity_sliding_drawer.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="Drag the control at the bottom"
android:textSize="20dp"
tools:context=".SlidingDrawerActivity" />

<SlidingDrawer
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="250dip"
android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/slideButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="^"
>
</Button>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:text="Button 1" >
</Button>

<Button
android:id="@+id/Button02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:text="Button 2" >
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button03"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:text="Button 3" >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this great library:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Same pattern implemented in google play music.

Comment: tks, that is awesome as well but I marked the other post as answer since it came in first. Cheers!